# Intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT not filltering for RTF

Tags: android, android-intent

I am setting up a file picker intent but its not filtering for RFT files.

```
private void openFilePicker(){
    Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    fileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    fileIntent.setType("*/*");
    String[] mimetypes = {"text/plain", "text/html", "text/richtext", "application/rtf", "application/x-rtf"};

    fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);

    String title = getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_title);

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, title);

    if(fileIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivityForResult(chooser, GET_FILE_CODE);
    }else{
        //display error message here
    }
}
```

This code filters for txt and html files but not for rtf.

[image]

I got the mime types from here: https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/

Answer (score 1):

The list of mime types is missing `text/rtf` including this allows rtf files to be filtered for.